# SPRING webflux global method security

Tags: spring-webflux

I am writing an application using spring reactor project. I have to use spring security annotation like @Secured, @Authorised
Is it possible to enable global method security with spring webflux version 5.0.1RELEASE?

Comment: use @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity